# Extract JSON with presto SQL without knowing the keys

Tags: sql, json, presto

JSON data is as below:

```
{"banned":[false,true],"shadow_banned":[false,true],"profile":[{"name":"Htet AAA","phone_number":"9597927098","email":"haavai27@gmail.com"},{"name":"Htet AAA","phone_number":"9597927099","email":"haavai29@gmail.com"}],"suspend_reason":["","ManualBan"],"subscriptions":[{"welcome":true,"promotion":true,"cancellation":true,"receipt":true},{"receipt":false,"cancellation":false,"promotion":false,"welcome":false}]}
```

I want to use presto sql to get a table as below:

```
Key (path)                  old value           new value
 banned                     false               true
 shadow_banned              false               true
 profile#phone_number       9597927098          9597927099
 profile#name               Htet AAA            Htet AAA
 profile#email              haavai27@gmail.com  haavai29@gmail.com
 suspend_reason                                 Manual Ban
 subscriptions#welcome      true                false
 subscriptions#promotion    true                false
 subscriptions#cancellation true                false
 subscriptions#receipt      true                false
```

Others:
Actual records have different keys.  I just take one record as an example.  It means the "Key (Path)" column is not fixed.

How can I do it through presto SQL?

Comment: I would say that it would be far far easier to implement this using some extension function written in java then using presto build in ones. Especially if nesting can go deeper than one level.

Comment: I see.  would like to utilise the existing presto infra hence prefer to use presto.